# Codeigniter open paypal redirect url in popup

Tags: laravel-5, paypal

I am using paypal REST API SDK. I want to open the redirect url in popup & if payment is success, then close it & update the payment status in previous/original window or tab. Like this

[image]

Comment: set the window height & width.